# Image and description inside DIV

Tags: css

I'm trying to put an image and its description at the bottom of the image (and over the image with the opacity 0.8). Both the elements are inside a div element. But enable display the title.

```
.title {
    opacity:0.8;
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    height:40px;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    bottom:0px;
    z-index:2;
    clear:both;
}

.tilebg {
    position:relative;
    top:0px;
    height:100%;
    z-index:0;
    opacity:1;
}
```

I've made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wvcNC/1/) with example

Comment: a fiddle will be more helpful

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wvcNC/1/

Comment: your fiddle is showing the title

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Hmz4q/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how positioning works:

`position:relative` - this sets the current element as the origin point (0,0)

`position:absolute` - this sets the position of an element in respect to its origin. If the parent has `position:relative`, that becomes the origin. Otherwise, it goes up the HTML tree until it finds one, defaulting to BODY if none is defined.

So: parent = relative, child = absolute

```
.item {
    opacity:1;
    background-color:grey;
    margin:20px;
    margin-left:20px;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    position:relative;
    background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/vdDQgb.jpg);
}

.title {
    opacity:0.8;
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    height:40px;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    z-index:2;
    clear:both;
    font-size:12px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! It works well ! I am using the img tag for the background image because i want to fade in image on load. but if i use background-image than i would not be able to fade in image. And this box is displayed on ajax request, So it is more difficult. any solution to that?

Comment: Sure, you just fade the containing DIV.

Comment: It is important to show the titles before it loads the image. Because there are many on one page.

Comment: If you use RGBA (alpha channel) on the container instead of opacity you can fade the image and the label independently.

Answer (score 1):

I would encourage you to use the new [`figure`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/figure) and [`figcaption`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/figcaption) elements since they were created for this very purpose:

```
<figure>
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/200" />
    <figcaption>This is the caption.</figcaption>
</figure>
```

​With the following CSS:

```
figure {
    width: 300px; height: 200px;
    position: relative;  /* Permits placement figcaption absolutely */
}

figcaption {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0; left: 0; width: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.8); /* Semi-transparent background */
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qu4a3/1/